# ¿Cómo quitar los ejes (axis) en los charts asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Hola tengo la siguiente gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero quitarle los números que salen abajo del eje x y no encuentro la propiedad.

mi codigo es el siguiente

```
 protected void Chart2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     byte[] Datos = null;
     List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
     Datos = selectAlarmas(6943);
     for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
     {
         graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
     }
     Console.Write("\n");
     foreach (int i in graficoY)
     {
         Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
     }
     Console.Write("\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
     {
         Chart2.Series["Senales1"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
     }
 }




<asp:Chart ID="Chart11" runat="server" Height="105px" OnLoad="Chart11_Load" Width="1036px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Line" Name="Senales">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea BackColor="Black" BackSecondaryColor="Transparent" Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
 </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: y si agregas tu código? :D recuerda que somos desarrolladores

Comment: No veo que construyas desde C#, podrias agregar el codigo de la vista, supongo que tienes algo como `<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debrías poder deshabilitarlo de esta manera:

Para el eje X

```
Chart2.ChartAreas["NombreDelArea"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

Para el eje Y

```
Chart2.ChartAreas["NombreDelArea"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false
```

En tu caso `"NombreDelArea"` es `"ChartArea1"`